# How can I get my Canon Pixma MX 310 Printer working?

Tags: printing, canon

How can I get my Canon Pixma MX 310 Printer to work with Ubuntu?

Comment: Is it the printer or the scanner or both that don't work?

Comment: I dont have the driver for both.

Comment: For the printer http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=823753 and for the scanner http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1004561 . If you are successful at getting either or both to work please add an answer. I don't have that particular printer so can't test the effectiveness of the fixes. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The MX printer drivers (and many more) are part of the gutenprint library. It seems it is not installed by default anymore. Just install them via:
`sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint`
If not automatically recognized you need to manually add the driver via the printer settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Canon website:

http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010697.asp

Download the MX320 driver (the driver contains all drivers) download the deb and install for both printing and scangear. This should get printing and scanning working.